# get_term() returns value for prior post instead of current post

Tags: php

I have a custom taxonomy. I would like to display child term name, parent term name.  My code displays the child term name.

However, the parent term name is for the post prior to it. The first post's parent term name is blank.  How do I correct the code?

```
$term_id = $location->parent;
$term_name = get_term($term_id )->name;
$name = $term_name;              

if ( $has_location && $locations = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'acadp_locations' ) ) {
    $location_links = array();
    foreach ( $locations as $location ) {                       
        $location_links[] = sprintf(
            '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
            esc_url( acadp_get_location_page_link( $location ) ), 
            esc_html( $location->name )
        ).",  ".$name;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are assigning a value instead of checking it in your if-loop. Use == instead of =

Answer (score 0):

In the if statement's condition replacing the assignment operator(=) with conditional(==) should resolve your issue.

Comment: I did that, and all of the parent locations (on the wrong posts) disappeared.